# What does this mysterious code do?

Tags: algorithms

I came across some code and I'm trying to crack the case as to what it does:

for $0 \leq f \leq l < len(A)$, the function is

```
def foo(A, f, l):
  if f == l:
    return A[f]
  m = (f+l) // 2
  x = foo(A, f, m)
  c = 0
  i = f
  while i <= l:
    if A[i] == x:
      c += 1
    i += 1
  if c > (l - f + 1)/2:
    return x
  return foo(A, m+1, l)
```

My first guess was that it returns the majority element because the while loop and the return seems to convince me of that but when I test some input

```
>>> a = [1,4,3,2,1,1,4]
>>> myst(a, 0, len(a) - 1)
1
```

But 1 is not the majority element as it doesn't appear more than half the times. Anyone up for the challenge to find the postcondition? The help would be appreciated.

Comment: If there is a majority element, it is returned. Otherwise, you recurse on the latter half of the input.

Comment: is there some sort of closed-form way of saying that because I've just come to something similar. @YuvalFilmus

Comment: Puzzling mod here: not really appropriate for Puzzling: it's a _question_ but not really a _puzzle_. @joyusbro, I won't _answer_ this since I suspect it's either homework or job-interview material, but if the intention of the function is what I think it is then I think you're on more or less the right track. If you were writing a function to return the majority element of an array, what would you _want_ its behaviour to be when there isn't one?

Comment: By the way, the function doesn't return the most common element. For example, on $1,1,2,3$ it returns $3$ rather than $1$.

Comment: I think @joyusbro appreciates that, hence their use of "majority" rather than, say, "most common".